# Is it possible to add a revision to an API using Bicep?

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-bicep

I'm tried to add a new revision using Bicep using the resource 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2022-08-01' but I get validation errors like 'Can't change property Name for non-current revision' and 'API with specified name ... already exists'. One of my experiments looked like something like this:

```
    resource apiManagementBackendApi 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2022-08-01' = {
  name: 'somename;rev=2'
  parent: apiManagementResourceInstance
  properties:  {
    apiType: 'http'
    description: 'Description'  
    apiRevision: '2'
    apiRevisionDescription: 'Changed by bicep'
    displayName: 'Some name'
    format: 'openapi+json'
    path: 'somepath'
    protocols: [
      'https'
    ]
    subscriptionRequired: false
    type: 'http'
    value: loadTextContent('somefile.json')
  }
}
```

Has someone an idea how to construct a working example?

Answer (score 2):

Tried repro'ing the issue but can't.

I'm going to guess there's some disparity in the name/revision that your are supplying with what already existing.

---

Here's what I did, keeping the name and apiRevision consistent didn't cause any problems ;

```
param revision string = '3'

resource apim 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2021-01-01-preview' existing = {
  name: apimName
}

resource apimService 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis@2021-04-01-preview' = {
  name: '${servicename};rev=${revision}'
  parent: apim
  properties: {
    path: serviceApimPath
    displayName: serviceDisplayName
    serviceUrl: baseUrl
    protocols: [
      'https'
    ]
    subscriptionRequired: apimSubscriptionRequired
    apiRevision: revision
    apiRevisionDescription: 'Updated by bicep'
  }
}
```

[image]